# Javascript slider [rcarousel] - How to use multiple sliders at one website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a javascript slider on my website. Everything is OK but when I try add multiple sliders, it doesn't work. I can use only first arrows to change position of slider. Secod and others sliders (arrows of these sliders) doesn't work.

Here is demo: http://majk23.vot.pl/slider/index.html

I know it's becase an IDs and CSS classes are using multiple and javascript code doesn't know about it but I tried to add an something unique to class names or IDs and it still doesn't work.

In DOC (http://ryrych.pl/rcarousel/#examples) of rcarousel we can find: "multiple carousels on one page", but in this demo author doesn't use an arrows so it doesn't help me: http://ryrych.pl/rcarousel/examples/multi.html

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is your code? css ?

Comment: If you look at DEMO - in code of my website you can find all codes. This script contain a few .css files and a few .js files so it's so much to publish everything here.

Comment: @Majkson I found your issue, Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because both the carousel have the same id's for the prev and next arrows like `ui-carousel-next` and `ui-carousel-prev` also the `div which holds the carousel has the same id's`

**Important:** Never have same id's for multiple elements. In your entire DOM the id's must be different. Also explaining your code.

```
               $( "#carousel ").rcarousel({
                    visible: 1,
                    step: 1
                });
                
                $( ".ui-carousel-next" )
                    .add( "#ui-carousel-prev" )
                    .hover(
                        function() {
                            $( this ).css( "opacity", 0.7 );
                        },
                        function() {
                            $( this ).css( "opacity", 1.0 );
                        }
                    );
```

The first line `$( "#carousel ").rcarousel()` here since you have the same id `carousel` for 2 different div's the result of `$( "#carousel ")` is only the first element jquery can find in the DOM starting from top. This is the reason the plugin is working only for the first one as it is the only one which is selected by jquery selector which you have used.

**Solution:**

Make two different id's to your div's and apply the plugin individually.

OR

Use class names on the divs and then apply the plugin by using the jquery selector with class name. Eg: `$( ".carousel ").rcarousel({})` where your divs will have the class carousel. Let me know if this helps

**EDIT :** Since you asked for an example. Here it is

Make changes to both your div by removing the id's and adding new class names.

```
<div class="ui-carousel carouselContainer" style="width: 500px; overflow: hidden; height: 400px;">
<div class="ui-carousel carouselContainer" style="width: 500px; overflow: hidden; height: 400px;">
```

Now add the plugin by looping the divs like below,

```
$.each($('.carouselContainer'),function(i,v){
       $(this).rcarousel({  //here $(this) will refer to the single div that is in iteration
          visible: 1,
          step: 1
        });
      // your other stuff's goes here
   });
```

**Edit 2:** After looking into the plugin documentation I found out how to set elements of choice to the next and prev arrows of the carousel (). The plugin has default values in it which always work on `"#ui-carousel-next"` and `"#ui-carousel-prev"` So the arrows for you were working only for the first carousel (as only the first element will be selected in the DOM when selecting from an ID), We can override this by setting custom values. To do so change your code to below.

These are you two divs: **NOTE** I have diff Id's for the div's and the arrow anchor tags.

```
          <div class="container">
                <div  id="a_carousel" class="carousel">
                    <a href="http://ryrych.pl"><img src="images/001.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="http://google.pl"><img src="images/002.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="http://niezalezna.pl"><img src="images/003.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="a_ui-carousel-next" class="ui-carousel-next"><span>next</span></a>
                <a href="#" id="a_ui-carousel-prev" class="ui-carousel-prev"><span>prev</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="b_carousel" class="carousel">
                    <a href="http://ryrych.pl"><img src="images/001.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="http://google.pl"><img src="images/002.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="http://niezalezna.pl"><img src="images/003.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="b_ui-carousel-next"  class="ui-carousel-next"><span>next</span></a>
                <a href="#" id="b_ui-carousel-prev" class="ui-carousel-prev"><span>prev</span></a>
            </div>
```

The the script would be as below for both the div's, Note the new navigation option.

```
           $( "#a_carousel ").rcarousel({
                visible: 1,
                step: 1,
                navigation: {
                           next: "#a_ui-carousel-next",
                           prev: "#a_ui-carousel-prev"
                }
            });
            $( "#b_carousel ").rcarousel({
                visible: 1,
                step: 1,
                navigation: {
                           next: "#b_ui-carousel-next",
                           prev: "#b_ui-carousel-prev"
                }
            });
```

And replace your CSS with

```
            .container {
                width: 220px;
                position: relative;
            }
            
            .carousel {
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .carousel img {
                border: 0;
            }

            .ui-carousel-next, .ui-carousel-prev {
                width: 60px;
                height: 100px;
                background: url(images/arrow-left.png) #fff center center no-repeat;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            .ui-carousel-next {
                right: 0;
                background-image: url(images/arrow-right.png);
            }

            .ui-carousel-prev {
                left: 0;
            }
            
            .ui-carousel-next > span, .ui-carousel-prev > span {
                display: none;
            }
```

Here is the details from the plugin
[image]

**EDIT 3:** To make even easier for you I have created a working example and uploaded the entire project into sendspace.com and the here is the link [ForMajksonHTMLCarousel](https://www.sendspace.com/file/bec03h)
You can download from there and see the links.html in examples folder to find your solution.

Comment: When I try change IDs for classes - it doesn't help me because I have still the same problem - when I try use first arrows, second arrows are using too... I can't add individualy ID for everything part because then I have to change this ID into many files and CSS classes. When I have a 50 x sliders on my website, I would have to add 50 classes and change everything in js code.

Comment: Ok what you  can do is  you can have same class names to all the docs then do a $.each on this class loop through all the divs and apply the plugin. This way u are dealing with classes but still applying plugin individually. And make sure IDs don't repeat, remove it off completely if you can't make it unique.

Comment: Can u give me an example?

Comment: @Majkson check my answer, I have updated it with an example

Comment: OK, I understand but what with arrows? The problem is in arrows because there is the same ID as in all cases. Can you give me example what I should to do with arrows also?

Comment: No, arrows are added into HTML code: `<a href="#" id="ui-carousel-prev"><span>prev</span></a>` and second: `<a href="#" id="ui-carousel-next"><span>next</span></a>`

Comment: Yes, you can look into demo. In every slider I have to add manually arrows.

Comment: I am not able to see any code written to add the HTML for arrows nor Add the scrolling functionalities to the carousel

Comment: follow this URL and look into HTML code: http://ryrych.pl/rcarousel/examples/links.html

Comment: Here is screen for you: http://s10.ifotos.pl/img/demopng_seqxpse.png Lines of these code: 64 and 65.

Comment: I already took a look into your code as well, I am sure the arrows are being applied by the plugin, You can see in the HTMl because when you do `$( ".carousel ").rcarousel({})` the plugin will automatically add the arrows. And the script you see related to arrows are to just make its opacity toggle when you hover it. Thats all

Comment: If you had tried my metod as suggested in answer I am sure you will get everything working fine

Comment: I edited everything what you said and arrows still doesn't work: http://majk23.vot.pl/slider/index.html

Comment: I still see the same HTML, You still have the same repeated id's. What have you changed? Nothing is changed in that link.. its all the same.

Comment: @Majkson the answer is the ones which I have suggested saying solution.  I dont see any of my suggestions being used in your code and how can you tell me its not working still without even trying?

Comment: Please remove cookies or open this URL by other browser... http://s5.ifotos.pl/img/demopng_seqxhps.png

Comment: Now I see the changes, But also remove the repeated id's from the arrows, First try removing the HTML of the next and prev things. and see what plugin does for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104396/discussion-between-majkson-and-reddy).

Comment: When I removed this HTML code, arrows don't show on my screen so this HTML code is important and arrows must be adding manually. Look into demo.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat

Comment: OK but I don't know how (I never use chat here). Can you invite me to chat?

Comment: just click on the link,, the link is in your comment itself... 4th comment above

Comment: I replaced everything with your instructions but I can't see an arrows on my website. Can you look into HTML code and check what is wrong? http://majk23.vot.pl/slider/index.html

Comment: The arrows are put by CSS.. Those are images. Check your css

Comment: Anyways I have the complete working HTML file with me I will share it with you tomorrow.. ie in next 8-10 hours

Comment: OK so if you can share it for me - it would be great!

Comment: I edited an url to arrows and now I can see the arrows but it work in bad way. Look: http://majk23.vot.pl/slider/index.html

Comment: Can you explain me why didn't you add the css?? I saw the code, And I dont find the css I gave you.

Comment: @Majkson I have uploaded a working HTML into sendspace.com and I am sharing the link with you. Please find the updated answer.

Comment: I updated .css here: http://majk23.vot.pl/slider/lightbox.css But I downloaded your files and I can see - that's work fine. I have to go out but when I come back, I check everything and finally I check your answer as "helpful". Thank you for your help bro!

Comment: No problem, I will be glad if you get it working... Lol so much time spent on this.

Comment: I have one question for your solution. Is it possible to add once this code to .css: http://pastebin.com/Rk05J0v7 ? Now when I have 50 x slider on my website, I have add this code to css 50 times.

Comment: I just wrote the css for the id's but you can write it for the class, that way you just write it once and it will apply for all 50 x sliders.